# highcharts heatmap drilldown link on yasix

Tags: highcharts

I created highcharts heatmap with drilldown. Drilldown has link on xaxis lable. Could I have link only on yaxis? And remove link on xaxis. Since my drilldown chart is associate to y not x.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'heatmap'
  },

  colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
    stops: [
      [0, '#7EAB55'],
      [0.5, '#FFFE55'],
      [1, '#B02418']
    ],
  },

  series: [{
    data: [{
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      value: 0,
      drilldown: 'animals'
    }, {
      x: 0,
      y: 1,
      value: 1
    }, {
      x: 1,
      y: 0,
      value: 2,
      drilldown: 'animals'
    }, {
      x: 1,
      y: 1,
      value: 1
    }],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      color: '#000000'
    }
  }],
  drilldown: {
    series: [{
      id: 'animals',
      data: [
        [0, 3, 1],
        [1, 1, 4],
        [2, 4, 3]
      ]
    }]
  }

});
```

This is example in fiddle. Thanks.
https://jsfiddle.net/lundi/jdc4mpk2/

Comment: You can use the `chart.inverted` feature to achieve the wanted result: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/82qapmoe/ Let me know if this an output which you expected to achieve.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel, I think it works. Then I have to invert x,y value too right?

Comment: Yes, by default the drilldown attaches only the `xAxis.labels` - the suggested solution is the easiest one without interference in the core code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Sebastian's suggestion, this is the answer.
You can use the chart.inverted feature to achieve the wanted result: jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/82qapmoe